# mp3 files in Webpack 5 w/ Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I'm currently working with next@11.1.2 and webpack v5 and got stuck for hours with fixing mp3 loading. I tried several other solutions from stack and GitHub. None of them worked for me.

```
Type error: Cannot find module 'public/sounds/bighit.mp3' or its corresponding type declarations.

  14 | 
  15 | // Assets
> 16 | import sound_bighit from "public/sounds/bighit.mp3"
     |                          ^
info  - Checking validity of types .%
```

Here is my last configuration for webpack:

```
const path = require('path')
const SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/sounds/')

module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { }) => {

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.mp3$/,
            incluse: SRC,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[contenthash].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'public/sounds/',
                    publicPath: 'public/sounds/'
                }
            }

        })

        // config.module.rules.push({
        //     test: /\.mp3$/,
        //     use: {
        //         loader: 'file-loader',
        //     },
        // })

        // config.module.rules.push({
        //     test: /\.mp3/,
        //     use: {
        //         loader: 'url-loader',
        //     },
        // })

        return config
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to import such files. Next.js supports putting the assets in `public` folder. Remove your custom webpack configuration and then simply do this:

```
<audio controls src="/sounds/bighit.mp3" />
```

Refer: [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called `public` in the root directory. Files inside `public` can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

---

Also, the error that you were getting was a TypeError, to fix it you can try:

```
// types/sounds.d.ts

declare module "*.mp3" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

Refer: [Importing Other Assets | TypeScript - webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets)